# Python read a multiline file and convert to map

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file which has the content as below:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}
```

In python, I want to read this file and store as a map (key-value pair).
I tried to use json, but it is giving some parsing error (`\n` is being added at the end of each line)

Here `value1`, `value2`, `value3` can be a multiline string.
As below:

```
{
    "key1": "value1
Jsjsjsj",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}
```

Let me know how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a usual JSON, so just use `json` module

```
import json

with open("file.txt") as fp:
    document = json.load(fp)

print(document)
```

To support multiline, you can use `multiline` package:

```
$ pip install multiline
```

```
import multiline

with open("file.txt") as fp:
    document = multiline.load(fp, multiline=True)

print(document)
```